# Не работает setCenter Яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Дано: на странице есть карта с несколькими маркерами. Есть список ссылок с координатами этих маркеров, по клику отрабатывает onclick=changeCenter(x,y)

Адрес 1

```js
function changeCenter(x,y) {

    myMap.setCenter(x, y);

}
```

переменные x и y передаются нормально, функция их съедает. Но карта тупо сбрасывается и ничего не происходит. 
Функцию подключил сразу после init карты.
Кто подскажет в чем беда? Так мало примеров setCenter в интернете. Допускаю что просто я не очень сообразительный)

на всякий добавлю инициализацию карты, может там что накосячил. Для пробы пока только с одной точкой пытаюсь разобраться

```js
  ymaps.ready(init);
    var myMap, 
    myPlacemark;
    function init ()
    {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("myMapId",
        {
            center: ["x", "y"],
            zoom: 18,
            controls: ["zoomControl", "fullscreenControl"]
        });
        myMap.geoObjects
        .add(new ymaps.Placemark
        (
            ["x", "y"],
            {
                balloonContent: "Адрес 1"
            }
        ))
        myMap.behaviors.disable("scrollZoom");
    }
  //ну и сама функция
    function changeCenter(x,y) {
        myMap.setCenter(x, y);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Метод [`setCenter`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#setCenter) - устанавливает центр и коэффициент масштабирования
>   карты. Центр задается в географических координатах. Возвращает ссылку
>   на себя.

Ваша функция выглядит следующим образом:

```
function changeCenter(x, y) {
    myMap.setCenter(x, y);
}
```

В документации яндекса к методу `setCenter` написано следующее:

> {Map} setCenter(center[, zoom[, options]])

Нас интересует первый параметр:

> Параметр: `center` (обязательное для заполнения поле)
>   Значение по умолчанию: `нет`
>   Тип: `Number[]`
>   Описание: Геокоординаты центра карты

Откуда следует, что в метод нужно передавать массив из двух чисел (чтобы это был массив - нужны квадратные скобки `[x, y]`). Думаю в этом и заключается причина сброса карты (некорректная работа, которая не ожидалась).

Касаемо `Placemark` и `Map`, там где вы передаете строки, что-то мне подсказывает, что туда нужно передавать не строки в виде `["x", "y"]`, а координаты в формате чисел (кстати тут указали верно - массив, но вот только строк).

Полезные ссылки:

- [Технологии Яндекса Map](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Map-docpage/)
- [Метод `setCenter`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#setCenter)
- [Placemark](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Placemark-docpage/)

Несколько примеров из документации, по использованию методов.

1. Инициализация карты из известных центра и уровня масштабирования:

   ```
   var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.74954, 37.621587],
        zoom: 10,
        // включаем масштабирование карты колесом
        behaviors: ['default', 'scrollZoom']
   });
   ```
2. Создание метки:

   ```
   var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([48, 40], {
       balloonContent: '<img src="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6114/82599242.2d6/0_88b97_ec425cf5_M" />',
       iconContent: "Азербайджан"
   }, {
       preset: "twirl#yellowStretchyIcon",
       // Отключаем кнопку закрытия балуна.
       balloonCloseButton: false,
       // Балун будем открывать и закрывать кликом по иконке метки.
       hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
   });
   geoMap.geoObjects.add(placemark);
   ```
3. Установка центра:

   ```
   myMap.setCenter([40, 50], 3, {
       checkZoomRange: true
   });
   ```

Из примеров видно, что значения координаты метки передаются в виде массива двух чисел: `[40, 50]`, `[48, 40]` и `[55.74954, 37.621587]`. Поэтому меняйте ваши  `["x", "y"]` - строки на числа, а в метод `setCenter` - передавайте массив.

Comment: Спасибо, очень подробно, в лицах, объяснили)) Вам надо преподавателем работать) Сейчас буду переделывать.

Заработало! Спасибо! Постоянно игнорю эти скобки у массивов)

Comment: @СергейКурамшин, увы, но преподавателям платят мало! Да и мне больше нравится писать код :) Если ответ вам помог и решил вашу проблему, вы можете отметить его в качестве правильного (галочка напротив ответа).